# Object tag content disappears in Safari/Chrome

Tags: html, cross-browser, embedding

We allow users of our application to embed a webpage containing a set of thumbnails into another third party webpage/blog etc. The embedding is done by using an object tag.

Each thumbnail provides an option to download original file. When user clicks on this option, the embedded content is disappearing in Safari 5.1.1 and Chrome 15.0 and instead "Could not render embedded content" is shown. Whereas FF 8.0 works correctly i.e. the embedded page stays there even after download, as it should.

The embed code we are using is like this -

```
<object data="http://myserver.com/em.aspx?e=FytXStk=" height="600" width="900" type="text/html">
<p>Could not render embedded content.</p>
</object>
```

Can anyone see what might be wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add target="_parent" for the download link. That did the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, if you just choose "Shockwave" instead of "Flash" from the drop down menu for video type, it all works perfectly.

Joomla Core Team has gotta do a better job on notifying developers and webmasters. It's obviously not obvious.